# What is the difference between zero-point and total energy of a molecule in the output of an ORCA FREQ calculation?

Tags: computational-chemistry, enthalpy, organometallic-compounds, density-functional-theory

I am trying to find the enthalpies of formation for a couple organometallics in ORCA and as a first time user I am a bit bogged down in the terminology. The [Gaussian](https://gaussian.com/wp-content/uploads/dl/thermo.pdf) manual has a section on these calculations (4.3 on page 14) and I am trying to confirm whether the "total energy of the molecules/atoms" is the same as the "inner energy" or "total thermal energy" you can get from the ORCA FREQ calculations.

Comment: The ORCA manual is fairly explicit on most things. One thing to check (with a small molecule, Hartree-Fock, small well-defined basis set) is to set the temperature. Those numbers that change have a thermal component. You should be able to get them to match betwenn the two programs.

Comment: @Spencer. The title or your questions is a bit misleading. Your are asking about the meaning of the output of a computer program not about a general definition. Could you correct it?